# text auto fadein when page opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a personal website and I want my page to appear blank initially. then the header fades in after a about a second and then the navbar  to fade in after that.

I've only learned how to make things fadein on click, so I looking for help on how to make them fade in automatically, once the page loads.

thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jxtdgj9s/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [.delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) in `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("document ready occurred!");
      // Add your animations is here:
      var myHeader = $('#header');
      myHerader.delay(500).fadeIn('300');
});
```

You can use your animations, or maybe use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score 0):

The animate.css library might be helpful for this: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

What you want to do is install the library and write some css like this:

```
<p class="animated fadeIn">Hello World</p>
```

When the page loads the animation will happen immediately without any click events.

Here is a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txx00wzr/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by having your items hidden, the use jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to trigger a [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). The `.fadeIn()` function accepts a callback parameter that allows you to chain your animations.

Here's a simple example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".header").fadeIn(5000, function() {
    $(".header nav").fadeIn(5000);
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.header nav {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Nav 1</li>
      <li>Nav 2</li>
      <li>Nav 3</li>
      <li>Nav 4</li>
      <li>Nav 5</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain javascript, I'd recommend you to specify `display: none;` style for all `body` children initially and then use the `onload` event like this: `<body onload="fade_in();">`
Function `fade_in()` must make elements visible. I used this line of code:
 `document.getElementById( "<element_id>" ).style.display = "block";`
If you want them appear not immediately, but smoothly, just set `transition` to the value you need.
 
To make delays, you can use `setTimeout()` function: [setTimeout() on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
If I have understood you correctly, the solution is that simple.